# Touching the screen while onTouch() is already being called

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

When I touch the screen and move my finger I do something (pullanimation1 and 2) and when I release the screen I do something else (fireanimation1 and 2). Sometimes, the user might touch the screen while pullAnimation or fireAnimation is running, I get errors as the animation then run several times. I would like to make sure the animations won't run more then once when the user touch again the screen.
NB: pullAnimation1 and 2, fireAnimation 1 and 2 are AnimationDrawable
Here is what I've done :

```
    image2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            boolean bool=false;
            boolean bool2=true;
            int action = arg1.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (bool2) {
            startAnimation(pullAnimation1,pullAnimation2);
            bool=true;
            }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (bool2==true){
                Log.w("GAMEACTIVITY","move");
                bool=true;
                bool2=false;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                startAnimation(fireAnimation1,fireAnimation2);
                bool=false;
                doPhotoTask();
                bool2=false;
                break;
            }
            return bool;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the hasStarted() and hasEnded() methods to determine if your animation is currently going. [See the docs for more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)

Some if statement like this might work:

```
if((fireAnimation1.hasStarted() == false) || (fireAnimation1.hasEnded == true()){
  startAnimation(fireAnimation1, fireAnimation2);
}
```

I imagine you may also need to use `reset()` after it is done playing in order or the methods to return proper values next time touch happens.

**EDIT:**
[AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) has an `isRunning()` method, which makes it even easier than View animations.

```
if(fireAnimation1.isRunning() == false){
  startAnimation(fireAnimation1, fireAnimation2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but pullAnimation1 and 2, fireAnimation 1 and 2 are AnimationDrawable so I can't use hasStarted, hasEnded, edit: Ill try isRunning !

Comment: That is the kind of thing you should include with your question =). See my edit.